# K8s readinessProbe and livenessProbe din't update

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, autopilot

I am using the GKE Autopilot cluster on GCP, yesterday I've changed the readinessProbe and livenessProbe urls in my deployment, and I see correct yamls in console. K8s is still trying check previous urls.

1. How to refresh configuration?
2. Which component does make this calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Since both are part of the deployment, you must redeploy it.

```
kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml
```

2. That would be the [kube-apiserver](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-apiserver/)